# Any alternative to testing if instance has received a method in rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

This is my first question, so forgive me if I leave anything out.

I've written a class in a Rails 3.2 app that lives in my `lib` directory.  I then have a rake task in my `lib/tasks` directory that requires the `lib` file, instantiates the class (let's call it `MailchimpExporter`) and executes an `export_all` method on the class.

The class is fully tested, but I'd also like to write a test for the rake task to ensure that `export_all` is called against the class when the task is invoked.

I started with something like:

**spec/lib/tasks/export_to_mailchimp_spec.rb**

```
it 'should export to all lists' do
  MailchimpExporter.any_instance.stub(:export_all)

  Rake::Task[:export_to_mailchimp].invoke

  expect(MailchimpExporter.any_instance).to have_received(:export_all)
end
```

But calling `#any_instance` in both the set-up and the assertion was throwing an error.  I instead changed it to the following, which got it running, albeit probably not the best code:

```
it 'should export to all lists' do
  chimpy = MailchimpExporter.new
  MailchimpExporter.stub(:new).and_return(chimpy)
  chimpy.stub(:export_all)

  Rake::Task[:export_to_mailchimp].invoke

  expect(chimpy).to have_received(:export_all)
end
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this, and also I'm hoping for an explanation of why you can't call `#any_instance` in both the set-up and assertion.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
it 'should export to all lists' do
  MailchimpExporter.any_instance.should_receive(:export_all)

  Rake::Task[:export_to_mailchimp].invoke
end
```

Comment: Niiiiice.  Is there some trade-off when using `should` instead of `expect` though?  Also, any insight into why you can't call `any_instance` in both assertion and the set-up?

Comment: Does this automatically stub the method, too?  It seems to, I just want to be sure that I'm not making any unnecessary API calls.

Comment: yes. Its basically saying that, any instance of MailchimpExporter should receive export_all message. The message will not actually be sent to the object.

Comment: I think you first implementation would work if you remove line `MailchimpExporter.any_instance(:export_all)`. This line does not mean anything. any_instance doesn't take any argument

Comment: Oops, that was a typo.  I meant `.stub(:export_all)`.  Thanks!